# How to access the environment of jinja2.Template

Tags: python, jinja2

When defining an environment including a loader, it is easy to add custom filters:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader, select_autoescape
env = Environment(
    loader=PackageLoader('tests', 'templates'),
    autoescape=select_autoescape(['html', 'xml'])
)
env.filters['rsttable'] = rsttable
```

But I struggle to add custom filters to a template created the `Template()` constructor:

```
from jinja2 import Template

def highlight(txt):
    return '**%s**' % txt

tpl = Template('hello {{name | highlight}}')
tpl.render(name='me')
```

yields:

```
TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'highlight'
```

The [Jinja2 doc](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#jinja2.Template) is quite cryptic for me:

> Template objects created from the constructor rather than an
>   environment do have an environment attribute that points to a
>   temporary environment that is probably shared with other templates
>   created with the constructor and compatible settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your template is an inline string, like in your example, use [`Environment.from_string()`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#jinja2.Environment.from_string) to acquire the template. (If it's a file, use `.get_template()`.)

This way it'll have the filters registered with the environment wired up.

```
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader, select_autoescape

env = Environment(
    loader=PackageLoader("tests", "templates"),
    autoescape=select_autoescape(["html", "xml"]),
)


def highlight(txt):
    return "**%s**" % txt


env.filters["highlight"] = highlight


tpl = env.from_string("hello {{name | highlight}}")
tpl.render(name="me")
```

Comment: I think this answer is good but would be even better if you explicitly mentioned that customization like adding filters is only available from environments.